# I want to calculate data to save in a row in django models.py

Tags: python, django-models

I have a models class that calculate the previous row to add value in next row. It always show error message "Please select the error below" even i was used  `null= True`

[image: Error Message]

```
def BMICal(height, PatientWeight):
    Hiin = str(float(height)).split(".")
    heightInc = ((((int(Hiin[0]) * 12) + int(Hiin[1])) * 2.54) / 100)
    final = PatientWeight/(heightInc*heightInc)
    return final

class PatTest(models.Model):
    TestId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    BS = models.IntegerField()
    BP = models.IntegerField()
    PatHeight = models.FloatField()
    PatientWeight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    BMI = models.FloatField(null=True)
    TEMPA = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        self.BMI = BMICal(self.PatHeight, self.PatientWeight)
        print(self.BMI)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.TestId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `blank=True` like `BMI = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)`

`null` will store empty values as NULL in the database.

`blank` mean that field is allowed to be blank.

Check [null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#null) and [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#blank) model field options.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful :)